# 4suite-xml for Python 3.6?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.6

I have an application that was written in Python 2.4 that I have taken over development for. I have since converted the application to Python 3, but parts of the application use 4suite-xml.

Is it possible to get 4suite-xml under Python 3?

I have tried 'pip3 install 4suite-xml' but it fails to install.

Comment: Currently it looks like no, you'll have to either port 4suite-xml to Python 3.6, or replace its functionality with another package.

Comment: Any suggestions for a drop in solution?

Comment: It depends on what functionality you're using, and Stack Overflow isn't really the place to ask for package suggestions, but the built-in `xml.dom` package might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try

Comment: the most feature-complete XML package these days is lxml. It is *not* a drop-in-replacement (nothing really is), but you most likely find features for whatever you need. `xml.dom` is IMHO a rather unusual suggestion. If anything I'd go for  `xml.etree`.

Comment: Thanks deets. I will keep that in mind. I have been wondering if it would be possible to build 4suite-xml from source for 3.6 without porting the code from python 2 to python 3. I have been able to successfully build 4suite-xml from source for 2.7, but I would rather get this project updated to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best solution was to replace 4Suite-XML with lxml given that the 4Suite-XML project is dead. In many respects, this reduced the amount of code that was needed to perform similar functions in 4Suite-XML.